# Remove NotNull field from hibernate entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have some field in my hibernate entity that I don't need to use anymore, so I removed it from the entity.
The problem is that now, when someone tries to save the new entity object to db, it ends up with exception that says "Field '{OldField}' doesn't have a default value". This is because the change in the entity doesn't affect MySql, and the old field still there and wants to get some value.

I can remove the old field from MySql, but I want to know if there is more elegant option to deal with this situation.

Thank's!

Comment: Why not alter the table field and set a default value?

Comment: Because it's two steps to handle the situation. I thought about solution that maybe makes the field nullable in case that the old field is removed from the hibernate entity(automatically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use default value option in MySQL. Just change the query parameters and default value.

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name> MODIFY COLUMN <Col_Name> <Data_Type> NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

or you can enable default value as NULL

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name> MODIFY COLUMN <Col_Name> <Data_Type> DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: Is there a way to add some configuration to hibernate that will make it automatically?

Comment: @YairCohen Yes, you can set default value using the hibernate. Ex: @Column(name="Col_Name",nullable=false,columnDefinition="bigint(20) default 0")
public Long getColName() {
    return colName;
}